# Create a pull request from a commit

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I had created a pull request earlier from a branch. Then, I have commited and pushed a new feature to the existing branch instead of creating a new branch. Now, when creating a new pull request, it shows all of the previous commits.

How can I transfer the latest commit to a new branch and then create pull request from the new branch?

I have explored for the solution and found two terms , I think that are related to my problem, **Cherry-Pick** and **Rebase**. But I am not clear about these terms.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: How many commits are there corresponding to the new feature?

Comment: [git cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html); [git rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html); [Git Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing); [Rebasing and Cherry-Picking Workflows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick).

Comment: There are two commits only @rubyprince

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout your branch as a new branch, say *add-ons*. So this branch, *add-ons*, will have all the commits you have made so far.

Then you checkout back to your first branch. Now if you want to remove the new commits from the branch which you have made a pull request, you can do rebase.

To remove commits, do: 
`git rebase -i HEAD~n`, where n will be the number of commits you want to be displayed. Your terminal screen will show n commits from your branch. To remove the last few commits, you can just remove the lines containing those commits completely. After that, quit the editor and do `git push -f` to force push your new commits for the branch.